# Why is Python not recognizing the newly inserted keys and values in the updated dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

The exercise I'm currently taking has three different dictionaries. What I wanted to do was update the first dictionary with keys and values from the other two with two different for loops like this.

```
def give_me_new(dic1, dic2, dic3):
    for key, value in dic2.items():
        dic1.update({key:value})

    for k, v in dic3.items():
        dic1.update({k:v})
```

After I updated, I housed all the keys inside a variable.

```
some_keys = dic1.keys()
```

What I decided to do was utilize a while loop to check to see if the key exists inside the dictionary. I created it like this

```
value = False
    while value == False:
        check_key = input('Lets check to see if key has been updated: ')
        if check_key not in some_keys:
            input('Nope, not in there. Press enter to try again')
        elif check_key in some_keys:
            return 'It is in there', dic1
            value = True
```

However, each time the input is prompted and the value is entered, it keeps showing that the key is not in there. What exactly happened inside the entire function created to cause this issue to come up?

Down below is the entire script created, please let me know what exactly I've done wrong.

```
def give_me_new(dic1, dic2, dic3):
    for key, value in dic2.items():
        dic1.update({key:value})

    for k, v in dic3.items():
        dic1.update({k:v})

    some_keys = dic1.keys()

    value = False
    while value == False:
        check_key = input('Lets check to see if key has been updated: ')
        if check_key not in (some_keys):
            input('Nope, not in there. Press enter to try again')
        elif check_key in (some_keys):
            return 'It is in there', dic1
            value = True



print(give_me_new({1:10, 2:20}, {3:30, 4:40}, {5:50,6:60}))
```

Comment: Why not just use `dic1.update(dic2)` and `dic1.update(dic3)`? There is no need to loop, or to create new single-key dictionaries.

Comment: Don't use `value == False`, use `not value`.

Comment: You have **integer** keys, not string keys. `input()` on the other hand returns strings.

Comment: In general, something like: `dic1.update({key:value})`  should just be `dic1[key] = value`, however, in this case, as Martijn Pieters points out, you just want `dic1.update(dic2); dic1.update(dic3)`.